# Law of Cosines to determine angle change along spiral

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, geometry

## The Spiral

I'm trying to place circles along the outside of an [Archimedean spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral). Shown below:
[image: Archimedian Spiral from 0 to 6 Pi]

```
ParametricPlot[{θ/(2*π)*Cos[θ], θ/(2*π)*Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 6π}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

## The Circles

[image: Circle placement]

To do this effectively I have been trying to use the [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent_rules) to determine the change in the angle.  I found the path that would contain the circle centers:

```
f[θ_] := {((π+θ) Cos[θ])/(2π), ((π+θ) Sin[θ])/(2π)}
```

Using the Law of Cosines for the following:

[image: Law of Cosines for this example]

Seems pretty straight forward, right?  Well, when I went to solve for the angle alpha Mathematica seems to have trouble.

[image: code]

seems to work "fine", but any subsequent evaluations don't seem to go smoothly.  In fact, any evaluation that does not contain Pi seems to fail, and an evaluation of the distance between the points shows that the angle is off (!=1).

[image: Distance]

## The Question

What am I doing wrong to be more than 5% off from what I expect.  Also, is there a more efficient and correct method to solve for the angle?

## An End Product

Thanks to KennyColnago for his response.
[image: Final Product]

Comment: is this in anyway related to [this](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/pi/art/)? ;o)

Comment: Could you provide the whole code generating the "end product" please? :)

Comment: @Öskå Yes, that is precisely what it is related to.  The code is quite boring with the exception of the code that KennyColnago helped me with.  I just generated a table where each part was {Color,Disk} counting up to 1000, and pulling a number off the value of Pi.

Comment: I also tried to do it as well but failed beautifully.., maybe you can paste it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qDsMe3J8

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/ieGhNPsP). I somehow reworked the code, extracted the colors from the [Brewer Palette](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/pi/art/img/color-rdylbu.png), and I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/VSNCbPB.png) with an execution time of .8s with 1000 digits :)

Comment: Much quicker than mine, that's for sure.  I'll take a deeper look at it later.  Have you tried reproducing any of the other graphics from that site?

Comment: No I have not.., they seem pretty tricky & not very well explained (since he has no reason to really explain it). But [that one](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/pi/art/img/links-pi-cristian.png) must be quite orgasmic!

Comment: I actually tried that one.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24370169/Output.pdf

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12640/discussion-between-oska-and-mrn16)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression I get for the angle angle increment $d$ is

```
(d^2 + 2d (Pi + t) + 2(Pi + t)^2 - 2(Pi + t)(d + Pi + t) Cos[d])/(4 Pi^2) = c^2
```

For your problem, $c=1$ and $t$ is the start angle of Pi/2. Solve the transcendental equation for d using

```
FindRoot[(d^2 + 2d (Pi + t) + 2(Pi + t)^2 - 2(Pi + t)(d + Pi + t) Cos[d])/(4 Pi^2) == 1
         /. {t->Pi/2}, {d,1.0}]
```

The answer is `d=1.241`radians. The second circle centre on your blue line is therefore at`f[Pi/2+1.241]={-0.896,0.307}`. The next angle increment is`d=1.0054`, found by solving with`t->Pi/2+1.241`.

However, you seem to be assuming that circles of radius 1/2 with centres on the blue curve are tangent to the red spiral. Not so. The circles touch the spiral function along a radial line from the origin, but they are not tangent to, or bounded by, the spiral.

**Edit**

I like your design! How about less random colourings, as in

```
Graphics[Map[{ColorData["DarkRainbow",Mod[#,Pi]/5 + Norm[CircleCentres[#]]^1.7/190], 
              Disk[CircleCentres[#],0.5]}&, NestList[NextAngle[#]&, Pi/2, 800]]]
```

where`CircleCentres[angle]`is your`f[theta]`, and`NextAngle`does a`NestList`of the`FindRoot`result.

Comment: The placement on the outside of the spiral is approximate, but becomes quite good after the first few turns.  Towards the center the approximation does break down though, I'm avoiding a lot of problems by starting at Pi/2, but I understand that the average distance between the one loop and the +2Pi loop does not equate to being tangential or, by necessity, bounded by the spiral.

Comment: It works though and far more efficiently than I was expecting from what I was working with earlier.