# Mapping data on Archimedes' spiral

Tags: function-construction, coordinate-transformation

I would like to map my data on Archimedes' spiral and preserve the distance between points on the curve.
The test data consists of 20 evenly spaced `{x,y}` coordinates:

```
data = Table[{i, i}, {i, 20}]
```

When I map the data to a spiral, the points are not evenly spaced anymore:

```
Show[ListPlot[{#[[2]] Sin[#[[1]]], #[[2]] Cos[#[[1]]]} & /@ data, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}], 
 ParametricPlot[{t Sin[t], t Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I found [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40740/law-of-cosines-to-determine-angle-change-along-spiral) that links to the [algorithm](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/pi/art/) that iteratively generates evenly distributed points on a spiral, but how can I apply this to my set of data points?

The final goal that I'm trying to achieve is to create a function that I can use with [`ImageTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageTransformation.html) that will remap an image that roughly resembles a line to an Archimedes' spiral.

Comment: Related: [(8454)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve)

Comment: @Pickett Thanks, I saw this, but again this uses the approach to subdivide a predefined curve. I don't think I can use this because my data will contain noise, and therefore I cannot directly assign my data points to the pre-generated points on a curve.

Comment: Maybe changing your `data` to `Sqrt[2 #] & /@ Table[{i, i}, {i, Range[0, 1/2 20^2, 1/2 20]}]` or similar ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks yes, this looks like I could use it

Comment: Somewhat related: [(655857)](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/655857)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using @b.gatessucks' hint, I solved it with the following transformation:

```
max = Max[data]; 
Show[
  ListPlot[{Sqrt[max #[[2]]] Sin[Sqrt[max #[[1]]]], 
            Sqrt[max #[[2]]] Cos[Sqrt[max #[[1]]]]} & /@ data, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}], 
  ParametricPlot[{t Sin[t], t Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing from Szcabolcs' answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve):

```
Off[FunctionInterpolation::ncvb]

PointsOnCurve[fun_, lim_, points_] :=

 Module[{arclength, curvepoints},

  arclength = 
   Derivative[-1][FunctionInterpolation[Evaluate @ Norm @ D[fun, t], {t, 0, lim}]];

  curvepoints = fun /. t -> # & /@
      Table[InverseFunction[arclength][x], {x, 0, #, # / points}] & [arclength[lim]];

  Show[
   ParametricPlot[fun, {t, 0, lim}],
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[curvepoints]}]]]

PointsOnCurve[{t Sin[t], t Cos[t]}, 20, 30]
```

[image]

```
PointsOnCurve[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, 2 Pi, 30]
```

[image]

Comment: You use the variable points twice, as number of points, and as a points list

Comment: @hieron Thanks, very attentive, I changed the answer

Comment: Switching off the message is not needed if you define spiral SetDelayed, which simplifies also the spiralpoints expression.

Comment: I am not looking for a function to generate the points, I want to remap the points that I will obtain experimentally.